# keep row with highest value amongst duplicates on different columns

Tags: pandas, duplicates, rows

I have a pandas dataframe like this one, where I can have rows with same combination of long and lat:

Initial df:

```
   lon  lat         name  value protection      a      b         c  score
0   20   10       canada    563        NaN    cat    dog  elephant   20.0
1   30   10       canada     65        NaN   lion  tiger       cat   30.0
2   40   20       canada    893        NaN    dog    NaN       NaN   20.0
3   40   20          usa      4        NaN  horse  horse      lion   40.0
4   45   15          usa   8593        NaN    NaN   lion       cat   10.0
5   20   10  protection1    100     medium    NaN    NaN       NaN    NaN
6   40   20  protection1     20       high    NaN    NaN       NaN    NaN
7   50   30  protection1    500        low    NaN    NaN       NaN    NaN
```

but what I want is:

wanted output:

```
   lon  lat protection      a      b         c  score
0   20   10     medium    cat    dog  elephant   20.0
1   30   10        NaN   lion  tiger       cat   30.0
2   40   20       high  horse  horse      lion   40.0
3   45   15        NaN    NaN   lion       cat   10.0
4   50   30        low    NaN    NaN       NaN    NaN
```

The output dataframe should contain rows with a unique combination of `long` and `lat` columns where only the row with the highest `score` is retained but if `long` and `lat` have duplicates and a value in the `protection` column these should be join into one

Comment: try `df.drop_duplicates(subset=['lon'],keep='last')`

Comment: I have tried `df.drop_duplicates(subset=['lon', 'lat'],keep='last')` but it's getting rid of too many rows

Comment: please post your dataframe as text so that we can reproduce your dataframe or add the output of `df.head(10).to_dict()` in your question

Comment: I edited my post with dfs as text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df = df.sort_values(by="score", ascending=False)
g = df.groupby(["lon", "lat"])
df_out = (
    g.first()
    .assign(
        protection=g.agg(
            {"protection": lambda x: ",".join(x.dropna())}
        ).replace("", np.nan)
    )
    .reset_index()
)

print(df_out)
```

Prints:

```
   lon  lat         name  value protection      a      b         c  score
0   20   10       canada    563     medium    cat    dog  elephant   20.0
1   30   10       canada     65        NaN   lion  tiger       cat   30.0
2   40   20          usa      4       high  horse  horse      lion   40.0
3   45   15          usa   8593        NaN    NaN   lion       cat   10.0
4   50   30  protection1    500        low    NaN    NaN       NaN    NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

one way is to create a func with your logic ad apply on the groupby:

```
def func(df1):
    df1 = df1.fillna(method='bfill')
    df1 = df1.fillna(method='ffill')
    return df1.sort_values('score', ascending=False)[:1]

result = df.groupby(['lon', 'lat']).apply(func)
```

Add reset index and selection to get the exact posted output:

```
result.reset_index(drop=True)[['lon', 'lat', 'protection', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'score']]
```

|  | lon | lat | protection | a | b | c | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 20 | 10 | medium | cat | dog | elephant | 20 |
| 1 | 30 | 10 | nan | lion | tiger | cat | 30 |
| 2 | 40 | 20 | high | horse | horse | lion | 40 |
| 3 | 45 | 15 | nan | nan | lion | cat | 10 |
| 4 | 50 | 30 | low | nan | nan | nan | nan |